# Internet connection goes down when I log in with another computer

Tags: windows, linux, router, internet-connection

I use my desktop PC and laptop concurrently. When I log in through my laptop, the internet goes down for a minute.

I use Ubuntu 10.4 on my desktop and Windows 7 on my laptop. I use a Pirelli router. The desktop is connected by wire, the laptop gets wireless access.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Desktop

```
      inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Laptop

```
   IPv4 Local address : 192.168.1.3 Mask : 255.255.255.0 Gateway : 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Can you please provide and ipconfig/ifconfig from the machines? Or at least IP/DHCP configuration information?

Comment: Is it safe to provide my ifconfig command outcome?

Comment: If we talking about your local IP's, yes it's safe. No body can find your computers ;)

Comment: Is it ok now?Does it makes any difference?

Comment: Looks like there is no IP conflicts if there were no other device connected on your network (eg.IPTV, VOIP device, NAS server) Did you call service for router? The router seems suspicious to me.

Comment: @RecNes No I didn't.There is a VOIP phone plugged in ,do you think it might be the cause ?

Comment: Yes it can. disconnect VOIP phone and try connect both computers same time.

Answer (score 3):

If both machine has same IP address, modems DHCP server might be crushed for a while... Check each machine's IP settings. If same change one of them to different IP or be sure both (at least one of them) configured for DHCP.